# How to change hair location?

Tags: particles, hair

How can I make the hair particles show on right side instead of the left without going onto *Particle Edit*?

[image]

I want the exact same hair amount and style but on the opposite side.

[image]

Comment: How did you achive appearence on current side?

Comment: I went onto particle properties along the right

Comment: Sorry I didnt get it, can you attach your simplified blend file with just a hair object via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to let us see?

Comment: Yes I've uploaded it. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/21qp8j3v

Comment: Disable or delete Mirror modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can use your head object directly.

- Select faces, go to *Data Properties* > add **Vertex Group** > *Assign*
- Add *Particle system* and under *Vertex Groups* > *Density* > choose created *Group*
  (now particle will grouw from this red faces)

[image]

- To let them grow only on one side, move *Particle* modifier above *Mirror* modifier in stack

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Disable the mirror modifier on the scalp:
[image]

Comment: But how do I stop it showing on the left side, the side it was showing in the picture above?

Comment: Just turn the scalp mirror off. Hair will only grow on the left half of the head.

Comment: You're right... Better?